# Validar peticiones a servidor Linux

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, ubuntu

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema con mi servidor en el cual tengo alojadas varias páginas web, últimamente mis páginas web han estado caídas o lentas, hice varias cosas para saber porque se encontraba con esos síntomas el servidor, cambien contraseñas del servidor, cheque que se estaba explotando la memoria ram porque se estaban haciendo muchas peticiones a mi servidor apache…
Como puedo validar del lado de mi servidor las peticiones que se hacen.
Espero que me puedan apoyar.
Saludos y excelente tarde.

Comment: Podés agregarle en los headers CORS, que hace que sólo aceptes peticiones del mismo servidor.